# Why is my image's Bytes per Row more than its Bytes per Pixel times its Width?

Tags: ios, video, uiimage, cgimage

I'm converting images to a MOV file, and had an interesting thing happen to me.  I logged my bits per color component, bits per pixel, and bytes per row.  Here's my code:

```
NSLog(@"Image width: %d, Height: %d", CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image));
NSLog(@"BPC: %d \ BPP: %d \ ByPR: %d", CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image), CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(image), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image));
```

Here's my output:

Image Width: 300, Height: 300  (everything's as expected)
BPC: 8   (8 bits per color...so far so good)
BPP: 32  (32 = 4 components ARGB * 8 bits per color...got it)
ByPR:1216  (300 px per row * 4 bytes per pixel = 1200 bytes per row)

Why am I logged 1216 bytes per row, and not 1200?  By the way, this isn't just a fluke.  When I create a video based on those numbers for buffer sizes, it works.  When I create it with 1200 bytes per row, I get some messed up aliasing effect.

Thoughts?!

Comment: Actually I need to do the same thing. Can you give me the code which converts images into mov? It's okay if you can't. My email is animesh1789@gmail.com . It'd be super grateful.

Comment: I've slightly different needs: new kidney and money. Any amount. It'd be cool if you can share. Tha-a-anks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The system likes images to be a multiple of 64 bytes per row, presumably for better performance due to cache line alignment.  1200 is not a multiple of 64, but 1216 is.

Comment: Interesting...any reason why, or is this pretty arbitrary?  Just a matter of making allocating buffers easier?  Also, do you have any documentation that might indicate this specifically for CGImage?  Thanks!

Comment: Like I said, I assume it is due to cache line behavior.  The CPU always loads a whole cache line at once.  I don't recall any documentation to point you at.

Comment: Is there any way to stop it from doing that? Can I set my bytesperrow?

Comment: If you have the raw pixel data with a different `bytesPerRow`, you can use `CGImageCreate`. If you're using the system's image loading functions, you get what the system picks.

Comment: Indeed I have raw pixel buffer from another image with different bytes per row. If I just copy everything over and create a new image, it creates a slanted image with pixels spilling over from the right and coming back from the left side. How do I identify and get rid of additional pixels from each row when copying?

Comment: You need to post your own question with full details.