# objective-c: cv::Mat to CVPixelBuffer

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

Below code converts `cv::Mat` to `CVPixelBufferRef`

```
CVPixelBufferRef getImageBufferFromMat(cv::Mat matimg) {
    cv::cvtColor(matimg, matimg, CV_BGR2BGRA);
    
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES], kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: matimg.cols], kCVPixelBufferWidthKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: matimg.rows], kCVPixelBufferHeightKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: matimg.step[0]], kCVPixelBufferBytesPerRowAlignmentKey,
                                nil];
    CVPixelBufferRef imageBuffer;

    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorMalloc, matimg.cols, matimg.rows, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, (CFDictionaryRef) CFBridgingRetain(options), &imageBuffer) ;

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
    void *base = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

    memcpy(base, matimg.data, matimg.total() * matimg.elemSize());
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

    return imageBuffer;
}
```

The problem is I am getting half the image

Original Image
[image]

After Convertion (i convert `CVPixelBufferRef` back to `UIImage` and store it using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` just for checking)

[image]

Interestingly, the image size of `Mat` and `CVPixelBufferRef` are the same.

Now, what I did was resizing the image just before `memcopy`, where the height is increased by 2 folds

```
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
    void *base = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

    cv::resize(matimg, matimg, cv::Size(), 1 , 2);
    memcpy(base, matimg.data, matimg.total() * matimg.elemSize());
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
```

Now the image size is still the same...

I want to badly know what's causing this behavior and I am sure I am missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15935294/9151842).

The system likes images to be a multiple of 64 bytes per row, presumably for better performance due to cache line alignment. As image resolution is `[1000 × 1000]`, not multiple of 64 hence bytes per row would default to `27840` don't know why... This was causing the problems.

Anyway, if anyone looking for the solution

```
CVPixelBufferRef getImageBufferFromMat(cv::Mat matimg) {
    cv::cvtColor(matimg, matimg, CV_BGR2BGRA);
    
    int widthReminder = matimg.cols % 64, heightReminder = matimg.rows % 64;
    if (widthReminder != 0 || heightReminder != 0) {
        cv::resize(matimg, matimg, cv::Size(matimg.cols + (64 - widthReminder), matimg.rows + (64 - heightReminder)));
    }

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES], kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: matimg.cols], kCVPixelBufferWidthKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: matimg.rows], kCVPixelBufferHeightKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: matimg.step[0]], kCVPixelBufferBytesPerRowAlignmentKey,
                                nil];
    CVPixelBufferRef imageBuffer;
    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorMalloc, matimg.cols, matimg.rows, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, (CFDictionaryRef) CFBridgingRetain(options), &imageBuffer) ;
    NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && imageBuffer != NULL);
    
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
    void *base = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
    memcpy(base, matimg.data, matimg.total() * matimg.elemSize());
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

//    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(converts(imageBuffer), nil, nil, nil);
    return imageBuffer;
}
```